# Hide axis in the plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a graph
[image: pic]
I need to hide axis there.
I have got it with

```
res.mca <- MCA(df)
```

I tried to use

```
axes=FALSE
```

but it returns

```
error in coord.var[, 1]
```

All code:

```
library(FactoMineR)
df <- read.table("tasks_correspondence_t.txt", header = TRUE)
row.names(df) = df$id
df = df[,-1]
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) df[,i]=as.factor(df[,i])
res.mca <- MCA(df)
```

And df looks like

```
            a   b   c   d   e
1mbank.ru   0   0   0   0   0
akbars.ru   0   0   0   0   0
alfabank.ru 1   0   0   1   0
avangard.ru 0   0   0   0   0
bank-hlynov.ru  0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Make an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and help would be more forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without modifying the contents of either `MCA()` or `plot.MCA()` since the axis labels are hardcoded. The latter is called from `MCA()` in case `graph = TRUE`, but even saving the object and then calling `plot()` won't help you because the issue is with `plot.MCA()`.

The relevant code in `plot.MCA()` is

```
  lab.x <- paste("Dim ", axes[1], " (", format(res.mca$eig[axes[1], 
                                                           2], nsmall = 2, digits = 2), "%)", sep = "")
  lab.y <- paste("Dim ", axes[2], " (", format(res.mca$eig[axes[2], 
                                                           2], nsmall = 2, digits = 2), "%)", sep = "")
```

Try changing it to

```
lab.x <- ""
lab.y <- ""
```

And see if it helps you.